# What is the correct way to avoid this error on C

Tags: c, string, loops

I have a this code, and i want to know why my code skips the scanf...

```
#include <stdio.h>

char nombre[20];
int tipo;
int edad;
int dias;

int repetir=0;

int main()
{

   while (repetir==0){
        int error=0;
        do{


            printf("Diga su Nombre: ");
            scanf("%19[^\n]", nombre);
            printf("Diga el tipo de Sala: ");
            scanf("%d", & tipo);
            printf("Diga la edad del Paciente: ");
            scanf("%d", & edad);
            printf("Dias de Hospitalizacion: ");
            scanf("%d", & dias);

            if ((tipo>4) || (tipo<0) || (edad<0) || (dias <0) ){
                printf("Eror al ingresar los datos");
            } else {
                error = 1;
            }
        }
        while(error==0);

        printf("¿Algun otro paciente? SI=0 NO=1");
        scanf("%d", &repetir);
    }

    return(0);
}
```

Its just a simple code, but when i run the code appears something like this:

```
 Diga su Nombre: (Name with spaces)
 Diga el Tipo de Sala (Integer Number)
 Diga la edad del Paciente (Integer Number)
 Dias de Hospitalizacion (Integer Number)

 //Check For errors

 ¿Algun otro paciente? SI=0 NO=1 (Pressing 0 To repeat)

 //Repeat

 Diga su Nombre: Diga el Tipo de Sala
 ....
 ....
```

The code no longer ask me for the string Data, i dont really know what i have to do in this case... Ty so much for your help!

### Update

This is what i tried... But just freezes

```
            // .....
            scanf("%d", & dias);
            //Dont really know what to do here :S
            int c; while ( (c = getchar()) == '\n' && c != EOF ) { }

            if ((tipo>4) || (tipo<0) || (edad<0) || (dias <0) ){
```

Comment: The scanf for the string gets "skipped" because you still have the newline in your stdin stream's buffer from when you scanned the repeat code. Add a getchar() call to fix that problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Inside `main()`, the line `char nombre[]= {0};` declares an array of size `1`.  Then you read into it using `scanf`, this overflows the buffer causing undefined behaviour.

Arrays do not automatically grow in C , they have a fixed size that you must assign when defining them. (Since you left the size blank, it worked out the size by counting the number of initializers).

Example of a fix:

```
char nombre[50];
// ...
scanf("%49[^\n]%*c", nombre);
```

NB . The global variable `char nombre[];` is a different variable to `main`'s `nombre` , and you don't currently use it, so I'd suggest removing one of the two (and giving the remaining one a size such as `50`).

---

There is another problem, if you execute this loop more than once. When you use `scanf("%d"`... , it extracts the characters for an integer, but it does not also extract the newline.  So next time when you come to `scanf("%[`...  , it reads the newline there.

To fix this, you need to manually consume the newline at the end of the loop, e.g.

```
scanf("%d", &repetir);

while ( getchar() != '\n' ) { }
```

Probably also do this after `scanf("%d", & dias);`. Technically it should be `int c; while ( (c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF ) { }` however in an interactive program that isn't an issue.

Also, the `%*c` is redundant, you can just make it `scanf("%49[^\n]"`. To be correct, you could also discard the rest of the line at this point.

Comment: Still the same, i remove the char nombre[] ={0} var cause it was useless but the code still skipping the scanf on that string...

Comment: Did you also fix the size of the first `char nomber[]` ?

Comment: You used the wrong size; the number in `scanf` must be one less than the size of the array

Comment: hmmm got stuck at your while, did not know how to make it work... it keeps on a loop and closes my program

Comment: post your code (as an append to your existing code - don't edit it into your existing code)

Comment: still failing the code... :S as before, the code still doing the same as before

Comment: omg it works!!!! i correct my code and it works!! srry about saying that does not work... my english is bad and i understand before when u say after ... TY So much!!!

Answer (score -1):

To get `nombre` as a string (char array), replace the scanf statement with:

```
scanf("%s", nombre);
```

Comment: cant do that, cause it will not gonna read the spaces and they are required.

Comment: Sorry. I guess I forgot that a name can have spaces.